# Visual Studio get/set "name" in color scheme

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to change the color of C# property access modifiers in Visual Studio 2010 (w/ ReSharper) and I can't for the life of me figure out what they are called in the list of display items.  Anyone know?

To be clear, the `get; set;` part of this snippet is what I'm trying to change:

```
public string Test { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's "ReSharper Method Identifier" and is also used for the color of method declarations.

Comment: Oh, as a bonus do you know how to have it *not* affect the color of a method name when used elsewhere?  Eg. the color of `MyMethod` in this: `MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that this is possible as there is only that single setting.

Comment: makes sense when you think about it.